# Force Outlook.MailItem.Forwad to specific account

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have to email accounts in Outlook - like:

- @a.com
- @b.com

My default account is @a.com.

I have a mail file saved as msg where the sender is @b.com.

If I use this code...

```
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.OpenSharedItem(fixSentResult.MsgFilename), Outlook.MailItem)
Dim forwardEmail As Outlook.MailItem = mail.Forward
forwardEmail.Display()
```

... the new forwarded mail's sender is @a.com, which is wrong - since the mail is saved with @b.com.

If I manually try to change sender afterwards to @b.com and sends it, I get a mail returned that I have no persmission to send on @b.com user ... hmmm.

My question:

When I "OpenSharedItem" - can I specify the account already, so it loads in @b.com and not in the default @a.com account? This might solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Are they both Exchange accounts? This works fine for a POP3/SMTP account. In case of Exchange, the item will be created for the primary mailbox.

Comment: As Dmitry mentioned,  you need to check your accounts. Please refer to this link:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-a-microsoft-exchange-account-47f000aa-c2bf-48ac-9bc2-83e5c6036793